# Is there any iphone app that allows user to retrieve the data through google credentials?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to allow the user to access the data of iphone app through the google credentials. Is there any app or source code to implement same on my iphone app.

Please suggest step by step. I tried a lot of times but not succeeded.

please anyone's help will be most appreciated.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: What data are you talking about?  Is this custom data your iPhone app is creating that you would like associated to their Google credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dead end, but try

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Here is a blog http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/

Hope it helps

Update: Found this http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-google-apis-in-iphone-app.html

Comment: I got 100 warnings and 82 errors after following four steps. It asking no such file for this line: "#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>" So I tried to add framework. but that framework does not exist. Please help me

Comment: You need to set the header search paths. Please have at look at their documentation

Comment: I am getting [--path /path/to/framework] [--output /path/to/output/file] as in log after adding the data source to the project and setting the header search paths. where I need to set the path for this. // get the --path argument
  NSString *const kPathKey = @"-path";
  NSString *const kOutputPathKey = @"-output";

Comment: I have added all the source and completed that 7 step given in the (http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/). Now which method I should call and where should I give input that is google credentials Please suggest any steps further.... Thanks in advance...Please